# Get updates from server via ajax in real time

Tags: ajax, jquery

Currently I have an ajax app that checks the server for updates every 10 seconds or so using setInterval(...).   This seems like a resource intensive way of doing this.  Is there are a more efficient way of getting updates from the server in real time?

Specifically I'm doing the above for a logging system.  I have my 'logs' page open on my second monitor for a CMS I'm developing.  Every 10 seconds the page checks the server for any new log entries.  This allows me to see whats going on in semi-real time as I'm developing.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [websockets API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/), but it is not supported on all browsers. The latest draft is supported by Chrome 14, Firefox 7 and Internet Explorer 10. If this is for development only, and you use on of those browsers, that shouldn't be a problem.

This API will allow the server to contact the client as well as the other way around, so no polling needed anymore. See also the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for an introduction.